# How does my scientific calculator calculate p/q ratio so accurately while the programming languages can't ? How are they programmed?

Tags: calculator

I have seen that my scientific calculator stores 99 digits after decimal. Why doesn't the programming languages use such precision ? Moreover, how can I achieve such precision if I want to ?

Comment: Scientific calculators are designed for a single purpose (floating point calculations), and don't have to deal with interaction with a CPU or memory alignment or other issues that general computer operations and programming have to deal with as well. *Why is a lathe so much more accurate at shaping wood than my pocket knife?*

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question!

To understand what happens, you must first familiarize yourself with how computers store floating point numbers: http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/

Typically programming languages offer two binary representations - one that uses 32 bits and one that uses 64 bits.

If you need more precision, you need a better representation and you can implement a [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) to obtain the result with arbitrary precision that you need.

You can take a look at Java’s implementation of [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)